# Удалить файл -> Commit. Можно ли получить удалённый файл из старого коммита?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

**Дано:**

Закоммиченный ранее файл. Удаляем его. Делаем коммит.

**Вопрос:**

Можно ли после коммита с удалением файла его получить из предыдущих коммитов?

Comment: Возможно вы хотите уточнить свой вопрос. Какая у вас цель?

Comment: @KromStern, я наворотил бездну кода от коего у меня болит голова. Во сне мне привиделся более простой способ решить задачу, но не полный. Засим я хочу сейчас сделать простым способом (удалив лишние файлы с кодом), а когда-нибудь потом, с бутылочкой какой взяться за старый код.

Comment: Сделайте ветку же! )

Comment: @KromStern, я не совсем уверен, что это будет "правильным" решением... Может мне никогда и не захочется возвращаться к старому коду и хочется в `master` оставаться)

Comment: Тогда ветку просто забудешь или грохнешь.

Comment: Смысл в чем, что ты можешь стартовать ветку с коммита который был ДО текущей переделки, и начать коммитить туда, и если не срастется - легко перейти обратно, и еще раз обратно если надо.

Comment: @KromStern, у меня этот кусок кода критически важен для проекта и если я его в другой ветке вести начну (при том, что я ещё и другие файлы правлю постоянно (да, знаю, что так не хорошо)) то потом, вернувшись на старую, многое придётся из этой ветки в мастер таскать... В общем идею я понял, спасибо, но, пожалуй, в данном случае пользовать не буду)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется, для это система контроля версий и существует (ну и для много чего еще). Чтобы всегда можно было вернуться назад к предыдущему состоянию проекта.

Comment: Ну, да, точно... Надо было мне не лениться, а потыкать в кнопочки на GitHub-е... Спасибо)

Comment: Если вопрос про интерфейс гитхаба, то ответ тот же, просто да, потыкать чуть в других местах чем если на клиенте на компе

Answer (score 3):

Если без привязки к гитхабу, то можно забрать нужную ревизию файла командой вида

```
git checkout <tree-ish> [--] <paths>
```

Например,

```
git.exe checkout 0f4f97a0c5384cd36ba066a56e870c84b371d1dd -- "folder/file.cs"
```